# sbt assembly: Exclude resources with MergeStrategy (multi-project build)

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

I have a multi-project sbt build.

I am in the sbt console in a sub-project.`

In the `src/main/resources` directory of this sub-project, I have a file: tonglu.conf

I have tried all the following merge strategies. None of them exclude the file. It still appears in the root of the assembly jar

```
 assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
    case PathList("src", "main", "resources", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith ".html"=> MergeStrategy.first
    case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith "Log.class" => MergeStrategy.first

    case PathList("tonglu.conf", ps @ _*)   => MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith "tonglu.conf" => MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps  contains "tonglu.conf"  => MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.toString()  contains "tonglu.conf"                   => MergeStrategy.discard
    case x => MergeStrategy.first
```

NOTE: I would happily remove the resources folder altogether

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My error must have been elsewhere.
The following line works:

```
case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith "tonglu.conf"                        => MergeStrategy.discard
```